# Having problems with PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, debian, session-cookies, session-variables

So to describe my Problem, im trying to login to my Website by creating a Session using session_start() etc and in the session folder it always creates the files and even when I login. But as soon as I hit login and it redirects me to my index page I get redirected back what means that the session variables im checking for are not set anymore after the redirect and I have no clue why :/
Using Debian 8 and PHP 5.6.4 already tried with newer Versions.
Help would be appreciated :)

Here is a code snippet, never had Problems on the old server with that.

```
    session_start(); 
$msg = "";  

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if ($username== "" || $password == "")
        $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
    else {
        $sql = $con->query("SELECT id, password, isEmailConfirmed FROM users WHERE name='$username'");
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
            $data = $sql->fetch_array();
            if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
                if ($data['isEmailConfirmed'] == 0)
                    $msg = "Please verify your email!";
                else {
                    $_SESSION["is_login"]=true;
            $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
                    $msg = "You have been logged in";
                    header('Location: https://web.site/index.php');
                    exit();
                }
            } else
                $msg = "Wrong username or password!";
        } else {
            $msg = "Wrong username or password!";
        }
    } 
}
```

Index:

```
if(!session_id())
{
session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{ 
header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: Code would be appreciated :)

Comment: Added some code :)

Comment: What's the index.php code that checks if user is logged in?

Comment: added the check

Comment: just call session_start every time, no need to check `session_id()`

Comment: k, but doesnt solve the problem :/